# How to extract documents with a certain name from a folder in a systematic way

Tags: data-transfer

I have a very large folder on my Computer containing, among other things, certain pdf files with similar names (B....). Is there a way that I could systematically extract these pdf's and put them in a new seperate folder?

Comment: You want to move all PDF's to a sub-directory? Or all files that start with `B*` to a sub-directory? Please update your question with your desired outcome.

Comment: All PDF's that start with a B

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

OK so lets assume your files are in `c:\users\robot112\misc` and you want all files that start with B and are .PDF's in a new sub-directory.

1. Start a new command prompt
2. `CD c:\users\robot112\misc`
3. `MD Sorted`
4. `MOVE B*.pdf c:\users\robot112\misc\sorted`

All your files that start with B and are .PDF's will now be in `c:\users\robot112\misc\sorted`